# Фильтрация и подсчет в смешанном списке с помощью лямбда-функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, lambda

Задан какой-то смешанный список: list1 = [4, 'gfg', 2,3, 'best', 'is', 3], необходимо при помощи лямбда-функции подсчитать вещественные числа. Я решил для начал отсортировать смешенный список при помощи:

```
list1 = ['4', 'gfg', '2,3', 'best', 'is', '3']
  
float_count = len(list(filter(lambda x: (type(x)=='float'), list1)))

print("Вещественные числа: ", float_count)
```

Но на выходе получается:

```
Float numbers:  0
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: В списке только строки. Некоторые строки изображают числа, но это только изображения. [Посмотрите сюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Comment: И ещё не называйте фильтрацию сортировкой, это разное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Во-первых, как написали в комментарии, в списке только строки. И перед тем, как узнать тип, их хотя бы нужно преобразовать к нужному типу
- Во-вторых, в отличие от js в пайтоне проверка типа возвращает не строковое представление типа, а сам тип, т.е проверка `type(var) == 'float'` всегда будет равна `False`

Что касается решения, то я бы прошел каждый элемент списка регуляркой

```
floats = list(filter(
    lambda x: re.match(r'\d+,\d+$', x, re.M), list1
))
```

А потом бы взял длину

Comment: Единственный нюанс, что регулярка в ответе пропустит `125,125,555` но это уже частности, поскольку в исходниках этого нет. Но все же я бы предложил использовать более строгий шаблон. Например `r'^\d+?[.,]?\d+$'`

Comment: @Александр, т.е. данный список не является  list1 = ['4', 'gfg', '2,3', 'best', 'is', '3']  смешанным?

Comment: @Namerek, можете, пожалуйста пояснить, что такое r в вашем выражении r'^\d+?[.,]?\d+$'

Comment: @HateFoube_2002, тестируемая строка начинается с группы цифр после которой возможны запятая или точка, после которых присутсвует группа цифр продолжающаяся до конца строки. А `r` это значит что управляющие символы типа `\\` читаются как есть.

Comment: @HateFoube_2002. если нужны только числа типа `float` то просто уберите знак вопроса после закрывающей квадратной скобки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо за замечание. Добавил знак конца строки в выражение. Знак начала строки добавлять не стал, тк `match` и так априори ищет сначала строки

Comment: @HateFoube_2002, нет. Это список строк

Comment: @Александр, на счет начала строки согласен. Есть такое дело.

Comment: @Александр, а можете подсказать пример смешанного списка

Comment: Но, если сделать  такой список  test_list = [4.8, 'gfg', 2, 'best', 'is', 3.8], то уже пройти каждый элемент списка регуляркой нельзя будет?

Comment: @HateFoube_2002, можно, но перед этим нужно будет все элементы привести к типу str. К примеру `floats = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(r'\d+[,.]\d+$', x, re.M), map(str, list1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется можно было так или я ошибаюсь?

```
test_list = [4.5, 'gfg', '2', 'best', 'is', '3',5.7]
res = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), test_list)
print("Вещественные числа: ", len(list(res)))
```

Comment: Если вам не надо приводить к float, то да. Можно так

Comment: @Александр,Я пошел иначе не стал приводить, а просто все начал проверять, так же можно?

Comment: @HateFoube_2002, ну если Вам не нужны строковые представления и Вы берете только данные типа `float` то тогда уж `res = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), test_list)`

Comment: @Namerek, мне нужен был смешанный список. Ранее у меня был просто список строк, как заметил Александр. Затем я сделал смешанный и уже пришел к этому решению. Спасибо за еще один вариант ответа!